# Dropdowlist in asp.net mvc with razor - set selected value and css class in one statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I need to be able to define a drop down list in my cshtml. I have some that are populated with the arrays coming from my model view, so I define them as such

```
   @Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist-Id", Model.ValuesForDDL, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

How do I set the selected value as well? (Please note that I need to be able to set the class too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the selected value with giving a selectlist object to dropdownlist

```
new SelectList(items, "value", "text", selectedvalue);
```

ex:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist-Id", new SelectList(Model.ValuesForDDL, "id", "name", 5);
Model.ValuesForDDL, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

Now the selected item in combo is the item that has id 5